# Possible to get previous test during test run

Tags: c#, unit-testing

We have quite a few automated tests, and sometimes one test will spill events to the next test, making the test after fail. To make it clear to everyone that this might be the case, I want to mention previous test/tests in the error message that will be presented.

I know this design is not optimal, but redesigning at this point is not something that will be done.

Is it possible to get the name or other data regarding previously run tests during a test run?

Comment: This is highly specific to whichever unit testing framework you are using, and may fall apart if your framework does parallel test execution.

Comment: I **strongly** suggest you design each test as an independent task. Tests **MUST NOT affect each other**. If you need data from another test then abstract that code in a separate method and invoke it from both tests. Each single test must be standalone. Don't forget that you're not optimizing run-time performance but you're testing correctness.

Comment: I know very well that tests should not affect each other, and I know it is bad design. I can sadly not decide how the legacy I work with was designed, and we are in no position to spend 100s of hours into redesigning it at this point; I just try to make something that will make it at least easier to find errors once these instances occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said

> test will spill events to the next test, making the test after fail

is a poor design of the tests. Each one should follow a [Hermetic pattern](https://www.packtpub.com/packtlib/book/Web-Development/9781783982707/3/ch03lvl1sec24/The%20Hermetic%20test%20pattern) and be self sufficient. Further more each test should try to revert the System in the initial state, on both pass and fail. This clean up logic can be placed in the TearDown method (e.g. [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=teardown&r=2.2.10)).

One easy way to

> get the name or other data regarding previously run tests during a test run

is to create a global place in which to store all the data from the run e.g. log file. If I had to do it (and assuming the tests are not run in parallel) I would log the name of the test starting and if it passes overwrite it with the next one or just pop it out. If a test fails in it's TearDown link the failed with the previous one using LIFO collection, like a [Stack](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) will help you if one test polutes more than one of the others.

Comment: Another solution would be to add a hook that runs at the end of each test. If there are any "spilled" events, either fail the test, or clean them up.

Comment: We already clean events after each test in the [TearDown], but that is not enough it seems, as some threads take longer still to do their work.

Comment: I ended up using a static variable which stores the results from TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name at each test. Seems to be working good enough.